# Synchronise Python Plotly/Dash Core Components Checklist State Across Multiple Instances

Tags: python, synchronization, state, plotly-dash

I am creating a dash app in python that can be accessed via a web browser which uses the dash core components checklist item. I provide a minimal example below

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Checklist(
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
                        {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
                        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
                    ],
                    value=['NYC', 'MTL']
                )
    ])
])

app.run_server(port=8050)
```

what this does is create an app that can be accessed on `http://localhost:8050/` showing three checkboxes. I would like the state of these checklist items to be synchronised across multiple users that may be accessing this page.

In other words, if I open two separate tabs with the address `http://localhost:8050/` after starting this app, say `tab 1` and `tab 2`. Any changes I make on `tab 1` to the state of the checklist should be reflected in the state of the checklist on `tab 2` as well. Right now, changes to the checklist state in `tab 1` do not affect the state in `tab 2`.

I imagine the solution involes using `@app.callback` events on some method with the `Input` and `Output` classes from the `from dash.dependencies` module but I haven't quite figured out the best way yet. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: it is complex problem. It would need to run JavaScript code which send state to server and it could keep it in memory or save in file/database. And it would need also another JavaScript code which periodically ask server for new state and update it on current page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is something for this.

You can try to use two `callbacks`.

When you change `checklist` then `callback` would save values in file.

And it would need object `Interval` to periodically run other callback which would get data from file and update values in `checklist` - this way value from one tab would be send to other tabs.

But it makes some problems because both callbacks may get values at the same time and when one callback saves new values from checklist in file then other callback may get old values and assing back to checklist. It would need more complex code then my example.

Because it can't run callback without `Output` so second callback uses `div` `placeholder-id` to get some output.

```
import os
import json
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Checklist(
            id='checklist-id',
            options=[
                {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
                {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
                {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
            ],
            value=['NYC', 'MTL']
        )
    ]),
    html.Div(id='placeholder-id'),
    dcc.Interval(id='interval-id', interval=2000)
])

lock = False
state = []

@app.callback(
    Output('placeholder-id', 'text'),
    Input('checklist-id', 'value'),
)
def checked(value):
    global lock
    global state
    
    print('checked:', value)
    
    lock = True
    state = value
    with open('data.json', 'w') as fh:
        json.dump(value, fh)
    lock = False
    
    return value

@app.callback(
    Output('checklist-id', 'value'),
    Input('interval-id', 'n_intervals'),
)
def update(n):
    value = state
    if not lock:
        if os.path.exists('data.json'):
            with open('data.json', 'r') as fh:
                value = json.load(fh)
                print('loaded:', value)
    return value
    
app.run_server(port=8050)
```